# change list of tuples to 2 lists - Python

Tags: python, tuples, ipython

I have a list of tuples (in this case its coordinates for latitude and longitude)

```
[(51.69768233153901, -5.039923897568534),
(52.14847612092221, 0.33689512047881015),
(52.14847612092221, 0.33689512047881015),
....]
```

I am trying to get them into 2 separate lists (one for latitude and one for longitude)

I cannot work out how to loop through to add them to the lists, so far I have:

```
lat = latlon_df.at[0,'LatLon'][0] 
lon = latlon_df.at[0,'LatLon'][1]
```

which identifies the first of each. Could someone show me how do create the 2 new lists?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check this excellent answer. It may help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558908/unpacking-a-list-tuple-of-pairs-into-two-lists-tuples

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Transpose/Unzip Function in Python (inverse of zip)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python-inverse-of-zip)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
coords = [(51.69768233153901, -5.039923897568534),
          (52.14847612092221, 0.33689512047881015),
          (52.14847612092221, 0.33689512047881015)]

lat, lon = map(list, zip(*coords))
```

Adapted from this answer here [Transpose/Unzip Function (inverse of zip)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python-inverse-of-zip)

Answer (score 0):

If I make a list of tuples with a list comprehension like:

```
In [131]: ll = [(i,j) for i,j in zip(range(10),range(5,15))]
In [132]: ll
Out[132]: 
[(0, 5),
 (1, 6),
 (2, 7),
 (3, 8),
 (4, 9),
 (5, 10),
 (6, 11),
 (7, 12),
 (8, 13),
 (9, 14)]
```

I can easily split it into 2 list with 2 list comprehensions:

```
In [133]: [i[0] for i in ll], [i[1] for i in ll]
Out[133]: ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

Yes, it involves looping over `ll` twice, but I'd end up looping over it many more times if tried to work out a way of doing it just one loop.  Sometimes the simple straightforward approach is better.

Having said that, there is a list version of `transpose` that does the job

```
In [134]: list(zip(*ll))
Out[134]: [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)]
```

This gives a list of 2 tuples, each with a 'column' of the original.  My original constructor can be simplified to

```
list(zip(range(10),range(5,15)))
```

So the `list(zip(*...` flips the list back and forth.

But:

```
lat = latlon_df.at[0,'LatLon'][0]
```

suggests that the list of tuples might actually be a `pandas` dataframe.  `pandas` probably has its own tools for indexing in this way.  You previously asked about this in dataframe terms

[Removing round brackets from a dataframe of lat/lon pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422043/removing-round-brackets-from-a-dataframe-of-lat-lon-pairs)

If the list was really a structured array:

```
In [143]: arr=np.array(ll, dtype='i,i')
```

The print display looks a lot like a list of tuples (though missing some ,)

```
In [144]: print(arr)
[(0, 5) (1, 6) (2, 7) (3, 8) (4, 9) (5, 10) (6, 11) (7, 12) (8, 13) (9, 14)]
In [145]: arr
Out[145]: 
array([(0, 5), (1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10), (6, 11), (7, 12),
       (8, 13), (9, 14)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

It is easy to select 'fields' by name:

```
In [146]: arr['f0']
Out[146]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)
In [147]: arr['f1']
Out[147]: array([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using list comprehension:

```
lats, lons = [[coord[index] for coord in coords] for index in (0,1)]
```

Note that using list comprehension is over a half order of magnitude faster than the `map-list-zip` approach for large coordinate lists:

[image]